# Akamai block my Comcast IP address - How to Fix?

Tags: ip, akamai, ip-blocking

My IP address has been blocked by AKAMAI. For this reason, I cannot connect to multiple websites such as united.com that use AKAMAI. My ISP is Comcast, and my box is a modem + router all-in-one. I have been unable to change my public IP address (I tried to change the MAC address of my computer and turn off the box, but it didn't work). Is there any way for me to change my IP, or am I blocked on those websites forever?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a VPN solution to get a different IP, or you could try contacting [Akamai Tech Support](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/support/) although I am not sure if they could do anything about it.

AFAIK Akamai has some security solutions like [IP reputation](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/client-reputation.jsp) that automatically "rate" IPs that are used for attacks across their platform, so Akamai customers can easily block IPs with a high risk rating (i.e. have been identified as source of attacks). You may want to run a malware scan on your network to ensure one of your devices is not being used by a BotNet (this happens way too often specially with IoT devices that use default passwords), and many times users are not aware of that until they get blocked by a security solution.

FYI Many large enterprises trust the Akamai platform to accelerate and protect their Websites and Apps, therefore the Akamai platform delivers around 20-30% of all the traffic on the Internet and their servers get tons of attacks each day, they tap on that attack DB to protect sites